How can I adjust the program dimensions in pyqt5?
Hello gys i have a problem when i link the designe.ui with the python code and i run it the Programme displayed very small , not like when i run it from QT DESIGNER
Images :


**MY CODE **
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
import os
from os import path
import sys


MAIN_UI, _= loadUiType("main.ui")

class MainApp(QMainWindow, MAIN_UI):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainApp,self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()

i have a problem when i link the designe.ui with the python code and i run it the Programme displayed very small , not like when i run it from QT DESIGNER
